# Show that if $q$ is an odd prime there does not exist a positive integer $n>5$ such that $3^n$ divides $\binom{2^q}{2}-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

This problem is directly related to my most recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900126/show-that-if-q-is-an-odd-prime-then-3-divides-binom2q2-1-part-1). I would like to go a step further now and show the following is true

> If $q$ is an odd prime then there does not exist a positive integer $n >5$ such that $$3^n\Bigg|\text{ } \binom{2^q}{2}-1$$

There is no deep motivation here just curiosity.

Comment: It's  not true: $\binom{2^5}{2}-1 = 495 = 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 11$.

Comment: I don't think what you say is true.  Let $q = 3.  {2^q\choose 2}-1 = 27.  3^4$ does not divide $27.$ 

 $3^2$ divides all  ${2^q\choose 3}-1,  3^3$ divides some.

Comment: Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: You question title does not make any sense.  You can't say "there exists an n in a range where a property is true for all n in range".  Particularly as what you apparently want to say is "there does not exist any n >= 5$.

Comment: You haven't told us what $n$ and $q$ stand for. Are $n$ and $q$ are positive integers?

Comment: Hmm? $q$ is an odd prime and explicitly $n$ is an integer. English is not my first language but I am certain the question is clear?

Comment: Ok, I missed info on $q$.

Comment: @rogerl I am not sure what your comment is showing but it does not dispute the claim I made?